# How to send array of struct in MPI to other process in C?

Tags: c, struct, mpi

Im having a hard time with this, I need to use a linked list with MPI to do some common operations over the list (sorting, deleting elements, etc). Anyway, most people I asked for this told me to use an array of struct instead of a linked list, so I did something like this.

```
struct{
    int proc; //process is in charge
    int info; //Information
};

struct list[100];
```

So, I want to send it to all process and work with it, anyway, im familiar with pthread but MPI is like another level to me, all I need basically is to share the whole list with all process and keep the changes in the list in all process, but Im not sure how to share the whole array with MPI_BCAST.

I already managed to create the list in the process MASTER, so all what I need to do now is share it with the rest of the process

Comment: `MPI_Bcast(&list[0],sizeof(list),MPI_CHAR,...)`

Comment: @user3528438 it's a struct containing two integers, what are you doing using `MPI_CHAR`?

Comment: @TimothyBrown It's just a big piece of memory, isn't it?

Comment: @user3528438, no, it is not. MPI is designed to work in heterogeneous environments too with those being more common nowadays than you might think. Sending "a big piece of memory" simply won't work in such cases and MPI is all about code portability.